# Web-scraper for a larger program

Tags: python, python-2.x, web-scraping

I have a web scraper that I use in a part of a larger program. However, I feel like I semi-repeat my code a lot and take up a lot of room. Is there any way I can condense this code?

```
def read_mail(mail):
        url = [mail] # Ignore this line, please.
        i = 0 # Ignore this line, please.
        droppedSource = '<td class="item_dropped">(.+?)</td>' # Gets whatever is inbetween the tags
        destroyedSource = '<td class="item_destroyed">(.+?)</td>'
        totalSource = '<strong class="item_dropped">(.+?)</strong>'

        droppedText = re.compile(droppedSource) # Converts regex string into something that can be interpreted by regular library
        destroyedText = re.compile(destroyedSource)
        totalText = re.compile(totalSource)

        html = urllib.urlopen(url[i]).read() # ignore the url[i] part of this line, please.

        dropped = re.findall(droppedText,html)
        destroyed = re.findall(destroyedText,html)
        total = re.findall(totalText,html)

        return("Info: " + str(dropped[0])+str(destroyed[0])+str(total[0]))
```

Answer (score 4):

- First of all I would recommend [not to use regex for handling HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/846892). You can use a library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for this.
- As all we're doing is finding the first match using tag name and class name we can define a function that uses BeautifulSoup to find such matches bases on the tag and class name. BeautifulSoup provides two functions [`find`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs)) and [`findAll`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)), `find` returns the first match and `findAll` returns all the matches.
- Note that in regex just to find the first match you should not use `re.findall`, better use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) which only returns the first match found otherwise `None`.
- On the last `return` line we can use string formatting.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from functools import partial


def find_by_tag_name_class(soup, tag, cls_name, many=False):
    if many:
        matches = soup.findAll(tag, {"class": cls_name})
        return [match.text for match in matches]
    else:
        match = soup.find(tag, {"class": cls_name})
        return match.text


def read_mail(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    # Instead of passing the same `soup` multiple times to 
    # `find_by_tag_name_class` we can create a partial function
    # with `soup` already applied to it.
    find_by_tag_name_class_soup = partial(find_by_tag_name_class, soup) 
    dropped = find_by_tag_name_class_soup('td', 'item_dropped')
    destroyed = find_by_tag_name_class_soup('td', 'item_destroyed')
    total = find_by_tag_name_class_soup('strong', 'item_dropped')

    return "Info: {} {} {} " .format(dropped, destroyed, total)

html = '''<td class="item_dropped">Foo bar</td><td class="item_dropped">spam eggs</td>
<td class="item_destroyed">Hakuna</td><td class="item_destroyed">Matatat</td>
<strong class="item_dropped">Some strong text</strong><strong class="item_dropped">Even more strong text</strong>'''

print read_mail(html)
# Info: Foo bar Hakuna Some strong text
```

---

Note that in the latest version of BeautifulSoup `findAll` has been renamed to [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all).

Answer (score 1):

Ashwini provided a good answer, mostly in the form of reminding me for some reason I wasn't using BeautifulSoup like I almost always do. I deleted my program and remade it vastly better (in my opinion) with the following code:

```
def read_mail():
        urls = [mail]

        for url in urls:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
            dropped = soup.find("td", class_="item_dropped").get_text()
            destroyed = soup.find("td", class_="item_destroyed").get_text()
            total = soup.find("strong", class_="item_dropped").get_text()
        print("Info : %s, %s, %s") % (dropped, destroyed, total)
```